# PayPal Integration with Classic ASP

Tags: paypal, asp-classic

I am trying to use PayPal's "Classic ASP", code that I found on their website, but there are NO INSTRUCTIONS (that I can find) on how to go about implementing it.  Does anybody know where the instructions are, or how to go about doing this implementation?  Much appreciated!

Comment: If it's the same sample code I've used in the past, it's pretty much a working solution that you can customise. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: There is an implementation guide (as a PDF) that came with the package, but I cannot figure out where it is.  I have the code, there are only two files (expresscheckout.asp and paypalfunctions.asp), at least that I know about.  Neither of these files have implementation instructions.  There has to be something out there.

Comment: From memory you should have more than two files. I just went looking online for the Classic ASP sample code but they don't seem to provide it any more (they say to use .NET version now). I'm sure I have a copy somewhere - will try and find it and let you know.

Comment: I can't find the sample code anywhere. The file name is PP_ASP_NVP_Samples.zip if you can find it anywhere online or if someone else can help. If you can't find it and still cant get your PayPal integration working let me know and I will strip out some code from a previous website. Are you wanting to use Express Checkout or one of the other services?

Comment: Hello Johna.  I did manage to find this "Integration Wizard."  I ran through, and read everything, including all of he code line, by line, but it is still not that clear on how to make it all happen.  Here is the URL: https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/done.php

Comment: Okay, good find. Now how do you want to use PayPal? Do you want to use flow 1 (checkout with PayPal button takes customer to PayPal pages to login, enter shipping address and pay, then come back to your site to confirm and complete) or flow 2 (customer chooses PayPal option, enters shipping address, goes to PayPal pages to sign in and pay, comes back to your site to confirm and complete)? Step 2 in the wizard is applicable for flow 1, and step 3 is applicable for flow 2.